# Bitwise operator precedence

Tags: sql-server

I just came across that baffles me in MSSQL.
If I do something like:

`SELECT 1 | 0 & 0`

The output is `0` - I would've thought that the `&` operator would have a precedence over the `|`operator.

Any ideas ? Is this a bug or an intended behavior in MSSQL ?

Comment: [Documented behaviour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx)

Comment: it's SQL Server 10.50, if that makes any difference. And before anyone points out, I understand that it's potentially a better practice to use brackets. But I'm just curious as it's sort of different to what I thought I understood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [SQL Server operator precedence table (SQL2k8+)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx) as @MartinSmith already referenced it in a comment this is how precedence looks like:

```
Level Operators

1     ~ (Bitwise NOT)
2     * (Multiply), / (Division), % (Modulo)
3     + (Positive), - (Negative), + (Add), (+ Concatenate), - (Subtract), & (Bitwise AND), ^ (Bitwise Exclusive OR), | (Bitwise OR)
4     =, >, <, >=, <=, <>, !=, !>, !< (Comparison operators)
5     NOT
6     AND
7     ALL, ANY, BETWEEN, IN, LIKE, OR, SOME
8     = (Assignment)
```

When two operators in an expression have the same operator precedence level, they are evaluated left to right based on their position in the expression.

### Your issue with bitwise operators

As you can see bitwise operators are all in the same level (3) that's why they're evaluated left to right, so in your example `|` is evaluated first and then `&`.

### Boolean logical operators are different

These are of course bitwise operators and not logical ones, which would of course evaluate in correct order since `AND` has level 6 and `OR` has 7. This means that `AND` would be evaluated first and `OR` afterwards.

Brackets are of course the preferred choice for any non trivial expression. In your case it seems trivial, yes, hence brackets weren't used, but since bitwise operators operate on the same level, they must be used when combining at least 3 operands **or** make sure you order operators in the way you want them to evaluate. In your case:

```
select 0 & 0 | 1
```

Would yield correct result.

### It hasn't always been this way

<strike>Bitwise operator precedence has been equalised **since SQL Server 2008**. [SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276%28v=sql.90%29) and older had bitwise `|` (along with exlusive or `^`) on a lower level (5), so your expression would evaluate correctly. Why Microsoft decided to put all bitwise operators on the same level is a mystery to me.</strike>

It turned out that [SQL Books Online were stating invalid real life processing](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/312359/operator-precedences-select-1-1-0-0) (Thanks to @MartinSmith). So they just updated operator precedence levels documentation page for SQL Server 2008. So apparently this has been working this way for a much longer time (maybe all the time).

Comment: I was just reading Sybase documentation - it seems to me that MSSQL retains this behavior from it.

Comment: @YS. I wouldn't judge on that so maybe they did, maybe they didn't. God knows why they equalised bitwise operators. Although *Code Complete* and other highly regarded resources always advise using brackets with expressions of more than 2 operands. For readability reasons of course. And apparently also for robust version-proof correctness. Your code would get a bug when upgrading database server from 2005 to 2008 if brackets aren't used.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik - [Think they just updated the docs and the behaviour hasn't changed](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/312359/operator-precedences-select-1-1-0-0)

Comment: @MartinSmith: Oh thanks for that. So it was a *documentation **bug*** after all. :)